# Creating a Custom JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

This is my first attempt to create a custom swing component. I am trying to create a JComboBox that will be used for numerous cells in a JTable. When my JTable is displayed the cells that should contain combo boxes look correct.
[image]
However, when I click on any of the boxes, the list is not displayed. Nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
public class TimeLineComboBox extends JComboBox<String> {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String item="";
private TimelineRecord timeLine=null;

public TimeLineComboBox(String[] list_,TimelineRecord timeLine_,String item_,Boolean editable_) {
    super(list_);
    this.addActionListener(listener());
    timeLine=timeLine_;
    item=item_;
}

private ActionListener listener() {
    ActionListener actionListener=new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            String value=(String) ((JComboBox<String>) e.getSource()).getSelectedItem();
            switch(item) {
                case "meat":
                    timeLine.meat=value;
                    break;
                case "monitor":
                    timeLine.monitor=Configuration.getInstance().getMonitorByName(value);
                    break;
                case "pit":
                    timeLine.pit=Configuration.getInstance().getMonitorByName(value);
                    break;
                case "event":
                    timeLine.eventText=value;
                    break;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(GUI.getInstance().getFrame(),"Internal Error: Unknown selection list: "+item,"Internal Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

    };
    return(actionListener);
}

}
```

Comment: Not sure why you think you need to create a custom combo box to use in a JTable. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for working examples showing the usage of a combo box.

Comment: Because I want to use a single class to create each of my comboboxes rather than individually creating boxes and listeners throughout my code that are all virtually identical except for certain variables.

Comment: Still no reason for a custom combo box. When you use a combo box in a table you don't write an ActionListener for the combo box. You would probably add a TableModelLIstener to the TableModel and an event will be generated when the value of a cell is changed and you can do your special processing. If you need more help post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.